# Cannot set my Android app to restricted bucket

Tags: android

I am trying to set my app to "restricted" bucket, based on this document https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#restrictive-app-standby-bucket.

```
adb shell am set-standby-bucket <Package> restricted
```

However, I always get 20 from this call

```
adb shell am get-standby-bucket <Package>
```

I tried this one too, but get the same 20.

```
adb shell am set-standby-bucket <Package> 45
```

The app is built target to 31. The device is Pixel 3a with Android OS 12 beta 4.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to *exit* the app
2. Run this command, it will set the app in ***restricted*** mode.

   ```
   adb shell am set-standby-bucket <Package> 45
   ```
3. Run this command to get the current App Standby mode

   ```
   adb shell am get-standby-bucket <Package>
   ```

- Any interaction with the app will/can change the *App Standby* value

---

Here is a description from [*Android Open Source Project*](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.java) regarding the values you get from `get-standby-bucket`

```
/**
 * The app has never been used.
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_NEVER = 50;

/**
 * Exempted battery optimizations and the Doze and 
 * App Standy does not apply to the app
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_EXEMPTED = 5;

/**
 * The app was used very recently, currently in use or likely to be used very soon. Standby
 * bucket values that are &le; {@link #STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE} will not be throttled by the
 * system while they are in this bucket. Buckets &gt; {@link #STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE} will most
 * likely be restricted in some way. For instance, jobs and alarms may be deferred.
 * @see #getAppStandbyBucket()
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_ACTIVE = 10;

/**
 * The app was used recently and/or likely to be used in the next few hours. Restrictions will
 * apply to these apps, such as deferral of jobs and alarms.
 * @see #getAppStandbyBucket()
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_WORKING_SET = 20;

/**
 * The app was used in the last few days and/or likely to be used in the next few days.
 * Restrictions will apply to these apps, such as deferral of jobs and alarms. The delays may be
 * greater than for apps in higher buckets (lower bucket value). Bucket values &gt;
 * {@link #STANDBY_BUCKET_FREQUENT} may additionally have network access limited.
 * @see #getAppStandbyBucket()
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_FREQUENT = 30;

/**
 * The app has not be used for several days and/or is unlikely to be used for several days.
 * Apps in this bucket will have more restrictions, including network restrictions, except
 * during certain short periods (at a minimum, once a day) when they are allowed to execute
 * jobs, access the network, etc.
 * @see #getAppStandbyBucket()
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_RARE = 40;

/**
 * The app has not be used for several days, is unlikely to be used for several days, and has
 * been misbehaving in some manner.
 * Apps in this bucket will have the most restrictions, including network restrictions and
 * additional restrictions on jobs.
 * <p> Note: this bucket is not enabled in {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#R}.
 * @see #getAppStandbyBucket()
 */
STANDBY_BUCKET_RESTRICTED = 45;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make the adb commands work. An alternative option to test the app is through developer options in device settings.

Developer options -> Standby Apps -> Select the app and select restricted bucket.

Note that opening the app again will move it out of this restricted bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If your app fulfills any of these [official exemption criteria](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/appstandby#restricted-bucket-exemptions), the system will not set the app standby mode to `RESTRICTED` (by ADB command or Developer Options > Standby apps).

In order to test how your app behaves recovering from being restricted, you must disallow all permissions causing the app to be exempt from being put into this mode.

To do this easily,

1. Remove your app and install and run it again.
2. Switch to another app before allowing permissions.
3. Set the app to Restricted.
4. Switch back to your app.